# HTTP request body to click a button and extract url in SSIS

Tags: html, http, ssis

I'm trying to get the link of csv file automatically using a get http request. I'm not sure what code I have to post to receive the link for the file. The following is the code for the button.

```
<div class="export-button-wrapper">
                        <button id="download-city-opp-btn" class="ui secondary button download-opp-btn" onclick="return downloadBidOpportunities('city');" data-segment-category="export data" data-segment-label="export by zip">Export by City</button>
                    </div>
```

[image: Image of the button and hyperlink]

The way this export process works is on clicking the export by city button it loads for sometime and then creates a hyperlink to the right of the button as seen in the image. I am trying to create a series of http requests to automatically capture the link for the csv file. Any help on this would great! Thanks

Comment: If you do right click on the button and there is no direct link to the file it means that the URL is generated at each download. therefore you need to create a web crawler in C#, Python, or whatever to actually click on that button and catch the file

Comment: Hi Francesco, Thanks for ur reply. The link is generated fresh at each download. Is there a way to capture this newly generated link using http requests in SSIS?

Answer (score 0):

If you do right click on the button and there is no direct link to the file it means that the URL is generated at each download.

There is no way to do this through SSIS.

Therefore you need to create a web crawler in C#, Python, PowerShell or whatever to actually click on that button and catch the file.

You can then run that script through SSIS.